How to fetch SectionedFetchRequest with the relationship object as its section id
There are two entities in my app, 'Card' and 'CardRecord', they have 1:n relationship, one card has many records. I have a view that needs to show how many records are there in each card, so here is my code:
@SectionedFetchRequest
private var sectionRecords: SectionedFetchResults<Card, CardRecord>

init(month: Int32) {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "month = %i", month)
    _sectionRecords = SectionedFetchRequest<Card, CardRecord>(
        entity: CardRecord.entity(),
        sectionIdentifier: \CardRecord.card!,
        sortDescriptors: [],
        predicate: predicate
    )
}

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        ForEach(sectionRecords) { section in
            CardExpansionView(card: section.id, num: Int32(section.count))
        }
    }
}

I only need to loop the sectionRecords because I only need the number of each section, and I need show the @ObservedObject Card, that's why I use the relationship object Card as the section id.
When I run the app in a simulator, an error occurred:
ForEach<SectionedFetchResults<Card, CardRecord>, Card, CardExpansionView>: the ID <Card: 0x6000025fdf40> (entity: Card; id: 0xe565b4b98e84a111 <x-coredata://292B0160-058F-48AE-BFCC-11196BF00552/Card/p24>; data: {
    cid = "6E3C25B7-2DC2-4538-B3D9-950A387C13AD";
    color = CardBrown;
    createTime = "2024-04-04 07:47:22 +0000";
    icon = "cup.and.saucer";
    name = "NO COFFEE";
    records = "<relationship fault: 0x60000063f6e0 'records'>";
}) occurs multiple times within the collection, this will give undefined results!

At the same time another question arises, the number of sections shown on the page is not correct and there are duplicate cards.
Then I add an attribute 'cardId' in the entity 'CardRecord' and change the sectionid to cardId
sectionIdentifier: \CardRecord.cardId!

When I run the app again... The error is gone, but the number of sections is still wrong and duplicates are still exist.
So, what is the problem and what do I need to do about it.
And finally, a question: how to sort the 'sectionRecords' by the 'section.count'
And thanks.

I am not surprised you get an error since each Card with more than one CardRecord will be referenced multiple times. That said I think you should scratch this idea altogether and take a look at derived attributes instead. If you add a derive count attribute on Card you can solve this with a normal FetchRequest. Here is one article on the subject.

Thank you for your answer. I've read that article carefully, but it doesn't seem to be working the way I want it to, I'm now trying to solve this using a different approach. Here is my code:

I will show my code in the following answer.

It's working well now and I think it can be optimized better(but I have no idea about it :)).

var body: some View {
        
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        ForEach(ranksFetcher.ranks, id: \.id) { rank in
            CardExpansionView(card: rank.card, num: rank.count, maxWidth: rank.width)
        }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    .onAppear() {
        if fetch {
            ranksFetcher.moc = moc
            ranksFetcher.maxWidth = viewWidth()
            ranksFetcher.fetch(yearmonth: yearmonth)
            fetch.toggle()
        }
    }
}

class RanksFetcher: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    var moc: NSManagedObjectContext?
    var maxWidth: CGFloat?
    
    @Published
    private(set) var ranks: [CardRankModel] = []
    
    func fetch(yearmonth: Int32) {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "CardRecord")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "month = %i", yearmonth)
        fetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = ["cardId"]
        fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
        
        // Defining column 'count'
        let expressDescription = NSExpressionDescription()
        expressDescription.resultType = .integer32
        let name = "count"
        expressDescription.name = name
        
        // Count witch column
        let cardId = NSExpression(forKeyPath: \CardRecord.cardId)
        let express = NSExpression(forFunction: "count:", arguments: [cardId])
        expressDescription.expression = express
        fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["cardId", expressDescription]
        
        var groups = (try? moc!.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [[String: Any]]) ?? []
        groups.sort { e1, e2 in
            let i1 = e1["count"] as? Int32 ?? 0
            let i2 = e2["count"] as? Int32 ?? 0
            return i1 > i2
        }
        
        var cardIds = [String]()
        for gp in groups {
            cardIds.append(gp["cardId"] as! String)
        }
        
        let cardsFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Card>(entityName: "Card")
        cardsFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "cid in (%@)", cardIds)
        let cards = (try? moc!.fetch(cardsFetchRequest)) ?? []
        let cardMap = Dictionary.init(cards.map { ($0.cid, $0) }) { $1 }
        let maxWidth = maxWidth!
        let maxCount = groups.first?["count"] as? Int32
        
        var data: [CardRankModel] = []
        for gp in groups {
            let cardId = gp["cardId"] as! String
            let count = gp["count"] as? Int32 ?? 0
            if let card = cardMap[cardId] {
                let cardRankModel = CardRankModel(id: card.cid!, card: card, count: count, width: maxWidth * (CGFloat(count) / CGFloat(maxCount!)))
                data.append(cardRankModel)
            }
        }
        
        ranks = data
    }
}

